# Laravel How Auth::attempt knows about Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables in my Database
1: Items
3: Users
and trying to log in the user and it is working properly, but my question is that i have not mentioned that from which table it will fetch the data, but it is fetching from the desired table automatically? Is it a Feature of Laravel or am doing something wrong? 
or i don't understand why this is happening?

Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('class'=> 'forming')) }}

    {{ Form::text('username',null,array( 'placeholder' => 'Username' ,'class' => 'insi')); }}<br>
    {{ Form::password('password',array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'paswor')); }}<br>
    {{ Form::submit('SignIn!',array('class'=> 'but-n')); }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

and the AuthController

```
class AuthController extends Controller{

        public function getLogin(){
            return View::make('login');
        }

        public function postLogin(){
            $rules = array('username'=> 'required', 'password'=>'required');

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

            if($validator->fails()){
                return Redirect::route('login')
                    ->withErrors($validator);
            }

            $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
                ), false);
            if(!$auth){

                return Redirect::route('login')
                    ->withErrors(array(
                        'Invalid'
                        ));
            }

            return Redirect::route('home');

        }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auth uses the model you have in your `file app/config/auth.php`:

If you are using the **Eloquent driver** for Auth:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => 'User',
```

If you are using the **Database driver**:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'users',
```

If you need to do authentication using more than one table, you have some options, one of them is to use a construction like this one to proceed login:

```
class Logon {

    public function loginViaEmail($email, $password)
    {
        if ($emailModel = Email::where('email', $email)->first())
        {
            return $this->login($emailModel->user_id, $password);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function loginViaName($name, $password)
    {
        if ($memberModel = Member::where('name', $name)->first())
        {
            return $this->login($memberModel->user_id, $password);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function loginViaId($id, $password)
    {
        if ($beingModel = Being::where('id', $id)->first())
        {
            return $this->login($beingModel->user_id, $password);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function login($id, $password)
    {
        $user = Member::find($id);

        if(Hash::check($password, $user->password))
        {
            Auth::loginUsingId($id);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And in your controller now you can do this:

```
$logon = new Logon;

if ( ! $logon->loginViaEmail(Input::get('email'), Input::get('password')))
{
    return "username or password invalid";
}

return "logged in successfully";
```

or

```
...

if ( ! $logon->loginViaName(Input::get('name'), Input::get('password')))

...
```

Comment: And just below that is the table to use, if you're using the Database driver instead of the Eloquent one.

Comment: Okay then is Eloquent and Auth both have same features?

Comment: Auth may use Eloquent to access your users table and authenticate them, but they don't have the same features, those are completely different things.

Comment: You are confused by Auth accessing your database. You have to understand that Laravel is made of a lot of different services, Auth is one service and Database is another one. Auth service may use Database service (Eloquent or Database, both are database services) , also the Session service may use the Database service, but those things are not really related, they are just using each othe and you can tell them to use different services (swap services). Let's say the database is too slow for your Cache service, you can tell Cache to use a different service: memcached.

Comment: Take a look at the docs to try to understand a little bit more of this: http://laravel.com/docs/, http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent, http://laravel.com/docs/security.

Comment: sir can we add more than one model and table in that Auth.php?

Comment: Looks like you need to use more than one table to do auth, right? But you never told us about that... Edited to provide some information that may help you accomplish that.

Comment: If you want to use authentication against multiple tables/models, then there are plenty of packages for it that allow you to do it in a nice easy way.